# Margins won't collapse when display is set to flex

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

When this code below has `display: block` the margins collapse, which is what i want but when I set `display: flex` then the margins don't collapse but I would like them to. I've tried fiddling around but I'm not sure how to make them collapse again.

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header>rob</header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-container">
      <p>tim</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>tom</footer>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/robcalcroft/pen/jKRvEE

Comment: It changes to see people asking about margin collapsing and not complaning about :)